# Displaying integer values in toast message

Tags: android

I am trying to create a BMI Application in Android 4.3. There are no compilation errors, but when I start running it on the emulator, I am getting the message - "Unfortunately, BMI has stopped." I can't understand, Where did I went wrong. Can any one please help me out? My java file is as follows -

```
package com.example.bmi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   double bmi;
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
    bmi = ( d2 / (d1*d1));

}
      public void showMessage(View v)
       {    

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your BMI is " + bmi,                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
         }

                }
```

And the xml file is as follows -

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="Height(m)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="Weight(kg)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:text="@string/condition"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
    android:text="Calculate" 
    android:onClick="showMessage"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I have done my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a runtime exception. One of the most useful skills you need to learn is where to find information about what happened. It's impossible to debug by simply guessing where the error is, logcat gives a detailed exception trace.

Comment: use try catch for Arithmetic calucation such  bmi = ( d2 / (d1*d1));

Comment: First of all please mention your question properly. you are asking about how to display integer in toast and in question description telling something else. Debug your project and get some relevant information regarding your failure then only we can help you..

Comment: Your code is absolutely wrong , I think null pointer exception is coming for you . You have not entered anything and you want the result. You need to take the values and calculate bmi on button click I mean in showmessage method , not in onCreate. Try to write the code sequentially .

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem solved. I have made some changes in the code, especially, I have used the method calculateBMI(weight, height) to calculate BMI, changed the datatypes of height and weight to float. Now I am trying to display the message in EditText, instead of toast. Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have number format exception as you are getting string from edit text without performing any action as the result of which it is crashing ..\
do it like that :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
double bmi;
Button calculate ;
EditText e1,e2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
 Button   calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double d1 = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
            double d2 = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
            bmi = ( d2 / (d1*d1));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your BMI is " + bmi,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

your code is wrong:

```
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
```

In `onCreate`, you can get nothing. Move them to `public void showMessage(View v)` after you type in something in your EditText

Answer (score 0):

this code throw exception:

```
double d1 = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
double d2 = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
```

bcs`e1.getText().toString()` == Empty string.

move this code on btn click listener

Answer (score 0):

change your showMessage method because you can not get input value before any event occurs.

```
public void showMessage(View v)
 {    

    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
     bmi = ( d2 / (d1*d1));
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your BMI is " + bmi,                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Display integer or double value by toast this way..

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.Add_btn){
    double Add=(Val1+Val2);
    Text.setText("Addition is: "+Add);


    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add result is: "+ Add,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    TextView toastMessage=(TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    toastMessage.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    toast.show();
}
```